# Can't solve this sql statement to archive my real goal

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT hotel.hotel_id, hotel.hotel_name, hotel.hotel_address, hotel.hotel_pic, 
room_accommodation.room_full_price 
FROM hotel 
INNER JOIN room_accommodation ON (room_accommodation.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id ) 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT MIN( room_full_price ) AS minPrice 
    FROM room_accommodation INNER JOIN hotel ON ( 
    hotel.hotel_id =room_accommodation.hotel_id ) 
    WHERE hotel.hotel_address LIKE '%bangkok%' 
)room_accommodation ON room_accommodation.room_full_price = room_accommodation.minPrice
```

This SQL can query each hotel that are in bangkok with a lowest rate of each hotel

But the problem is now I want to query all lowest rate of each hotel but when I cut

the condition where out the result just gave me only one lowest price of all hotel

what wrong and what should I do to archive this

Please Advice

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be greatly simplified - there's no need for a subquery based on the results you need:

```
SELECT hotel.hotel_id, 
       hotel.hotel_name, 
       hotel.hotel_address, 
       hotel.hotel_pic, 
       MIN(room_accommodation.room_full_price) as room_full_price 
FROM hotel 
INNER JOIN room_accommodation 
  ON room_accommodation.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id
  AND hotel.hotel_address LIKE '%bangkok%'
GROUP BY hotel.hotel_id
```

Note that for other DBMS's you would need to specify each non-aggregate field in the GROUP BY clause.  MySQL lets you get away without that - for better or worse.

Comment: WOW !! Thank @PinnyM That was so simply and fantastic to me 
you save my life and gave me a great idea

Answer (score -1):

i guess u are giving wrong alias to to ur inner query [room_accommodation]

ur query shows that u also have a table with name room_accommodation

```
SELECT hotel.hotel_id, hotel.hotel_name, hotel.hotel_address, hotel.hotel_pic, 
room_accommodation.room_full_price 
FROM hotel 
INNER JOIN ***room_accommodation*** ON (room_accommodation.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id ) 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT MIN( room_full_price ) AS minPrice 
    FROM room_accommodation INNER JOIN hotel ON ( 
    hotel.hotel_id =room_accommodation.hotel_id ) 
    WHERE hotel.hotel_address LIKE '%bangkok%' 
)***room_accommodation*** ON room_accommodation.room_full_price = room_accommodation.minPrice
```

Comment: @DavidGorsline I'm guessing he means "alias" and is pointing out that the original query isn't valid because it has both a table and alias by the same name.  A valid point although not clearly expressed.  Probably not a native English speaker.